# Disposal wires?

Tags: electrical, socket

In the circuit breaker, I have a switch labeled as "disposal". I have noticed in my pantry there is closed off square cover (electic cover) that has four screws. I loosened the screws to find 4 sets of wires each set had black white and red wire. Is there an intention for keeping that closed off and not having a socket plugs there?

I am the first owner of the home
House is built by ryan homes last year.

Comment: It sounds like a simple junction box for wire connections/splices, which must be accessible (handy to get at).  If you find what the wire circuit/s are for, might be able to add socket plugs/outlets/lights to it, but need to know what those are for first.

Comment: Please clarify the relationship between the labeled circuit-breaker you mention, and the junction box in the pantry. BTW that's exactly what that box is, a place for wires to be connected together in an enclosure; there was either no desire/need to have receptacles in there and/or the box is not big enough to accommodate all those wires *and* receptacle(s).

Comment: I just noticed that the disposal circuit breaker is a set of wires in that junction box. And the dishwasher label in my circuit breaker is another set of wires in the pantry junction box

Comment: Each set of wires is actually six wires and not 3 wires. Two reds two black and two white in each set. Each color is twisted together

Comment: That is what a splice is and must be in a box.  Make sure both breakers are off before working on those wires, very easy to mistake live wires for dead wires.

Comment: Do you have a garbage disposal in the kitchen? These wires may have been provided for powering a disposal.

Comment: @crip659 some of them were dead! So is it okay to make a plug outlet from the live wires?

Comment: All that you have said about the fact that each set correlate to a different item (dishwasher, garbage dispenser,..etc) is to true.

Comment: I plan to use the outlet that I will be making to hook kitchen appliances

Comment: That's a problem. Kitchen/pantry receptacles can only be on certain circuits. They must be 20A and power kitchen receptacles only.  You cannot put a receptacle on a dishwasher or disposal circuit.  I suspect two MWBCs are extended here, one is dishwasher/disposal, the other is kitchen receptacles 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in a location subject to the NEC if the wires connected to the breaker that is marked disposal are not connected to anything then you could re-label the wires and use for an additional "small appliance" circuit, but you can't put kitchen receptacle and disposal outlets on the same circuit. To understand the NEC requirements it helps to keep in mind that the Code specifically defines *outlet* as a point of connection of equipment, and *receptacle* as a type of outlet.

The NEC requires in 210.11 that two *or more* 20 amp branch circuits be supplied for small appliances, then later in 210.52 defines what those circuits can and must feed.

> **NEC 210.52(B)Small  Appliances.**
>
> **(1) Receptacle  Outlets Served.** In    the kitchen,    pantry, breakfast room, dining  room,   or similar  area    of  a   dwelling    unit,   the
> two   or  more    20-ampere   small-appliance branch circuits
> required  by  210.11(C)(1)    shall   serve   all wall    and floor   receptacle
> outlets   covered by  210.52(A),  all countertop  outlets covered
> by    210.52(C),  and receptacle  outlets for refrigeration   equipment.
>
> Exception No. 1: In   addition    to  the required    receptacles specified   by
> 210.52,   switched receptacles    supplied    from    a   general-purpose branch circuit  as  defined in  210.70(A)(1),   Exception
> No.   1,  shall   be  permitted.

(The above exception pertains to required switched lighting outlet requirements)

> Exception No. 2: In   addition    to  the required    receptacles specified   by
> 210.52,   a   receptacle  outlet to   serve   a   specific    appliance shall be  permitted to    be  supplied    from    an  individual  branch  circuit
> rated 15  amperes or  greater.
>
> **(2) No  Other   Outlets.** The  two or  more    small-appliance branch  circuits    specified   in 210.52(B)(1) shall   have    no  other outlets.

The critical points in the section are "shall feed all wall and floor" and "no other outlets", so wall and floor receptacle circuits in designated rooms have to be circuited as small appliance circuits, and can't feed an outlet in the cabinet for a disposal, dishwasher, or point of use water heater.

There may be further complications depending on the appliances you are connecting. Disposals often exceed the 210.23 limit of 50% circuit amperage  for equipment fastened in place that would allow it to feed other loads not fastened in place.